# A stronger verb than "to alleviate"

Tags: word-request

How to say if something finishes a pain completely not to some extent that the words " to alleviate" or "to mitigate " imply?

> The only thing you can do to ......... my pain is to tell me the
>   truth.

Comment: In this context alleviate works ncely.  No substitute is needed.

Comment: Are you speaking to a small child? to an adult?  to a medical professional? a lay person?

Comment: I have a hard time finding a situation where ‘the truth’ will completely eliminate the (emotional ?) pain instead of simply mitigate it.

Answer (score 8):

The medical word you are looking for is

> [eliminate](http://nutritionandhealing.com/2013/05/22/eliminate-chronic-pain-in-minutes/)

However, in your example the appropriate word is

> The only thing you can do to **end** my pain is to tell me the truth.

since "end" and "pain" tends to be a collocated for an emotional pain

> end the pain of a broken heart

Answer (score 6):

For the particular example given, a simpler word seems to fit better than a more medical or formal term. In this context, I would therefore suggest **stop** or **end**:

> The only thing you can do to **stop** my pain is to tell me the truth.

Or

> The only thing you can do to **end** my pain is to tell me the truth.

Comment: These words might be a bit too strong.  They remind me of "end my suffering", which is a euphemism for "die".

Comment: @Jasper both phrases appear fairly regularly in song lyrics and poems, so you might try googling "end/stop my/this/your pain" and see if the way they're used works for you. You'll also see "cure" and "heal" in lyrics, which are good if you want to emphasize the connection to physical pain.

Answer (score 5):

"Eliminate".

"Eradicate" is too strong.

"Make my pain go away" is not quite as strong as "eliminate".

"Heal" is appropriate in this context, but involves a different kind of pain during the healing.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean more literal sense by a different kind of pain during the healing, not emotional ? or does "to heal" convey a medical sense or feeling?

Comment: When a (literal) wound heals, it hurts.  The pain is more of an ache than the (often) sharp pain that (probably) went with getting injured.

When an emotional (figurative) "wound" heals, it can also hurt.  For example, there is the distress of realizing that things are different than you thought they were.  Similarly, this pain is often different from the original pain.

Answer (score 2):

The question states that the pain finishes completely, and not to some extent, so  why not use "completely" in the sentence?  "Completely relieve" seems to fit what you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 1):

In this context (intense emotional pain), I think "Ease" would do nicely:

> ...to ease my pain...

Comment: I would argue that "to ease" does not completely remove the pain as is stated in the question.  To ease falls more in line with "to alleviate" which he is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do to ..**erase**...... my pain is to tell me the truth.

"erase", in my view, works well to express elimination of "emotional pain", in part, because the latter is abstract. "erase memories" is another example.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.